# Thymeleaf 3 syntax to iterate List<List<T>>

Tags: java, arraylist, thymeleaf

Consider the following `List` of `List`'s:

```
List<List<SubSection>> listOfSubSectionLists
```

I need the two corresponding nestings of loops in my Thymeleaf 3.0.9 TEXT template looking like the following:

Template:

```
[# th:each="ssList, iterStat : ${listOfSubSectionLists}"]
    Title: Sub-Section [( ${ssList.iterStat.index+1} )]
    [# th:each="subSection : ${ssList.**?**}"] 
        Name: [( ${subSection.name} )]
        Address: [( ${subSection.address} )]
        Phone: [( ${subSection.phone} )]
    [/]
[/]
```

Is it possible to get the inner lists in the 3rd line in the template above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your variables are as described, the list is simply `ssList`.  So the code should be:

```
[# th:each="ssList, iterStat: ${listOfSubSectionLists}"]
    Title: Sub-Section [( ${iterStat.count} )]
    [# th:each="subSection: ${ssList}"] 
        Name: [( ${subSection.name} )]
        Address: [( ${subSection.address} )]
        Phone: [( ${subSection.phone} )]
    [/]
[/]
```

Some notes:

- `iterStat` is it's own variable (unrelated to ssList).  You can't access it with the expression `ssList.iterStat`.
- `iterStat.count` is equivalent to `iterStat.index + 1`

Comment: I was making it too complicated